# Java Contain method cannot find symbol

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, contains

I am trying to only print strings containing the word "The" from a text file but the contain method does not seem to be working. Is there any other way to do this or fix the contain method?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class FileNerd
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
{
    Scanner alpha = new Scanner(new File("E:\\temp_Larry\\NerdData.txt."));
    
    int maxIndx = -1;
    String text[] = new String[100];
    
    while(alpha.hasNext())
    {
        text[++maxIndx]=alpha.nextLine();
    }
    alpha.close();
    if(alpha.contains("The"))
    {
        System.out.println(alpha);
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: that won't even compile.  You need to call contains on each string element of your array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `contains` on `Scanner` object, you should call it on the lines that you read from file, that's the whole point of reading them, right? Iterate through lines and call `contains` on those lines like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i< maxIndx; i++) {
  // Do whatever with text lines
  System.out.println(text[i].contains("The"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Observed few mistakes in your code and try to remove it

1.Scanner alpha = new Scanner(new File("E:\temp_Larry\NerdData.txt."));
Corrected: Scanner alpha = new Scanner(new File("E:\temp_Larry\NerdData.txt"));

2.There is such method call contains inside the scanner class
Remove: if(alpha.contains("The"))
Correct:

Comment: 1.while(alpha.hasNext()){ System.out.println((text[++maxIndx]=alpha.nextLine()).contains("The"))}
    
2.for (int i = 0; i< maxIndx; i++) {
  System.out.println(text[i].contains("The"));
  }